# Jquery - replace multiple classes defined in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, toggle

Let's say I have the following div:

`<div class="device iphone5 black"></div>`

I want a toggle button to change devices. Therefore, the classes should be changed. But, not only `.iphone5` should be replaced, the color `.black` should be replaced as well.

I have the following array:

```
var devices = [
            '.iphone5 .black',
            '.nexus5',
            '.iphone4s .black',
            '.lumia920 .blue',
            '.s5 .white',
            '.htc-one'
        ];
```

How can I make a switcher that checks if a div with the `.device` class has one of the classes defined in the array, and then replace it by the next one? Something like:

```
<script>
$('.device').filter(devices.join())$('.device').is(devices.join("")
        .attr('class', 'device ' + devices[NEXT]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array, searching for all elements that match the current selector, and replacing the classes with the next array element.

You have to loop through the array in reverse. Otherwise, after you change `.iphone5.black` to`.nexus5`, the next iteration will change that to `.iphone4s.black`, and everything will end up with the last class in the array.

```
for (var i = devices.length-2; i >= 0; i--) {
    $(".device" + devices[i]).attr("class", "device " + devices[i+1].replace(/\./g, ' '));
}
```

Also, you need to take the spaces out of the values in `devices`. `.iphone5 .black` means to search for a child of `.iphone5` with class `black`, but you want these classes to apply to the same element, so it should be `.iphone5.black`.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Only need to figure out how to run the loop over and over again. Should I reset `i` at the end?